# Prove $3\cos{x}+2\cos{2y}+\cos{3z}+\frac{25}{16}\ge 0$ for $x + y + z = \pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $x,y,z\ge 0$ and $x+y+z=\pi$, show that
> $$f=3\cos{x}+2\cos{2y}+\cos{3z}+\dfrac{25}{16}\ge 0.\tag{1}$$

I found this $\frac{25}{16}$ is best,because when $z=0$,then
$x+y=\pi$,and
$$f= 3\cos{x}+2\cos{2y}+\dfrac{41}{16}=3\cos{x}+2\cos{2x}+\dfrac{41}{16}
=4\cos^2{x}+3\cos{x}+\dfrac{9}{16}=\left(2\cos{x}+\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\ge 0$$
when $$-\cos{x}=\cos{y}=\frac{3}{8}$$

but How to prove $(1)$

It must to  prove
$$f=3\cos{x}+2\cos{2y}-\cos{(3x+3y)}+\dfrac{25}{16}\ge 0 $$

Comment: Did you try Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remark*: Here is a proof without using calculus.

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $x + y \le 3\pi/4$

Since $u \mapsto \cos u$ is strictly decreasing on $[0, \pi]$,
using $\cos 3z \ge -1$, we have
\begin{align*}
 f &\ge 3 \cos (3\pi/4 - y) + 2\cos 2y + (-1) + \frac{25}{16}\\[6pt]
 &= - \frac{3}{\sqrt 2}\cos y + \frac{3}{\sqrt 2}\sin y + 4\cos^2 y - \frac{23}{16}\\[6pt]
 &\ge - \frac{3}{\sqrt 2}\cos y + \frac{3}{\sqrt 2}\sin^2 y + 4\cos^2 y - \frac{23}{16}\\[6pt]
 &= \left(4 - \frac{3}{\sqrt 2}\right)\cos^2 y - \frac{3}{\sqrt 2}\cos y + \frac{3}{\sqrt 2} - \frac{23}{16}\\[6pt]
 &> 0. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

**Case 2**: $x + y > 3\pi/4$

Using $x = \pi - y - z$, we have
\begin{align*}
 f &= -3 \cos(y + z) + 2\cos 2y + \cos 3z + \frac{25}{16}\\
 &= -3\cos y \, \cos z + 3\sin y\, \sin z
 + 4\cos^2 y + \cos 3z - 7/16\\
 &\ge -3\cos y \, \cos z + 3\sin^2 y\, \sin z
 + 4\cos^2 y + \cos 3z -7/16\\
 &=  -3\cos y \, \cos z + 3(1 - \cos^2 y)\, \sin z
 + 4\cos^2 y + \cos 3z -7/16\\[6pt]
 &= (4 - 3\sin z)\left(\cos y + \frac{-3\cos z}{8 - 6\sin z}\right)^2 + \frac{9}{4} \sin z + \frac{7}{16 - 12\sin z} + \cos 3z - \frac{23}{16}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{9}{4} \sin z + \frac{7}{16 - 12\sin z} + \cos 3z - \frac{23}{16} \ge 0 \tag{3}$$
which is true. The proof of (3) is given at the end.

We are done.

---

*Proof of (3)*:

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $z \in [\pi/6, \pi/4)$

We have
$$\cos 3z = \cos z \, (1 - 4\sin^2 z)
\ge 1 - 4\sin^2 z.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{9}{4} \sin z + \frac{7}{16 - 12\sin z} + \cos 3z - \frac{23}{16}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \frac{9}{4} \sin z + \frac{7}{16 - 12\sin z} + (1 - 4\sin^2 z) - \frac{23}{16}\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac{\sin z \, (3 - 4\sin z)(55 - 48\sin z)}{64 - 48\sin z}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}

**Case 2**: $z \in [0, \pi/6)$

We have
$$\cos 3z = \cos z \, (1 - 4\sin^2 z)
\ge \cos^2 z \, (1 - 4\sin^2 z)
= (1 - \sin^2 z)(1 - 4\sin^2 z).$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{9}{4} \sin z + \frac{7}{16 - 12\sin z} + \cos 3z - \frac{23}{16}\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& \frac{9}{4} \sin z + \frac{7}{16} + (1 - \sin^2 z)(1 - 4\sin^2 z) - \frac{23}{16}\\[6pt]
 ={}& \frac14 \sin z \, (16\sin^3 z - 20\sin z + 9)\\[6pt]
 \ge{}& 0.
\end{align*}

We are done.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch of solutions:

Eliminate $y$, we get

$$f=3\cos x+2\cos(2x+2z)+\cos 3z,$$

So we need to find the extrema on this triangle region $D: ~0\le x+z\le \pi, 0\le x,z\le\pi$

(1). Let the gradient $\nabla f=\vec{0}$, we get critical points. Plug in these critical points and we get the value for $f$, and they are candidates for the extrema.

(2). Find the extrema candidates on the boundary of region $D$, i.e. use Lagrange multiplier.

Finally, collect all candidates found in (1) and (2), compare them and find the extrema.

Comment: Can you add some details I'm new with Lagrange multipliers .(+1)

Comment: Here is a detailed description on this method, together with many examples. https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/lagrangemultipliers.aspx

Comment: Thanks you so much !

Comment: at the last setp  I think is very ugly,Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer with Hint Without lagrange multipliers here $a+b+x=\pi$:

Show that for $a,b,x\in[0,\pi/2)$ :

$$f\left(x\right)=\left(3\cos\left(x\right)+2\cos\left(2\left(\pi-b-x\right)\right)+\cos\left(3\left(\pi-a-x\right)\right)+\frac{25}{16}\right)\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)^{4},f'(x)\ge 0,f(0)=0$$

I can add details if needed .

For example we have for $x\in[0,\pi/4],a,b\in[0,\pi/2)$ :

$$g(x)=\left(\cos\left(3b\right)+1\right)\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)^4,g'(x)\geq 0,h\left(x\right)=\left(3\cos\left(x\right)+2\cos(2a)+\frac{9}{16}\right)\left(\tan\left(x\right)\right)^{4},h'(x)\geq 0$$